# win32com.client.Dispatch works but not win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, dispatch

i'm learning win32com for python and I've got a strange problem.

I'e trying to export Outlook Contacts in a List of Dictionnary. My code works perfectly with win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application). But it returns 0 contacts with win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application) that is supposed to be faster and "safer". Here's my code :

```
class MapiImport():
    def __init__(self):
        self.olApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
        self.namespace = self.olApp.GetNamespace(u"MAPI")
        # olFolderContacts = 10 :
        self.mapiContacts = self.namespace.GetDefaultFolder(10).Items

    def getContacts(self, *fields):
        contacts = []
        # Class == 40 is ContactItem
        # Class == 69 is DistListItem
        # Exclude ditribution list and others objects != ContactItem
        for contact in filter(lambda x: x.Class == 40,self.mapiContacts) :
            if not fields :
                ctact = dict((x.Name,x.Value) for x in contact.ItemProperties)
            else :
                ctact = {}
                for field in fields :
                    itemProp = contact.itemProperties[field]
                    ctact[field] = itemProp.Value
            contacts.append(ctact)
        return contacts

#====TEST SCRIPT====
myMAPI = MapiImport()
fields = (u"LastName",u"FirstName",u"Companies",
          u"HomeTelephoneNumber",u"Home2TelephoneNumber",
          u"MobileTelephoneNumber",
          u"BusinessTelephoneNumber",u"Business2TelephoneNumber",
          u"Email1Address",u"Email2Address",u"Email3Address",
          u"HomeAddress",u"BusinessAddress",
          u"Birthday",u"Anniversary",
          u"Body")
print(myMAPI.getContacts(*fields))
```

So when i replace :

```
olApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
```

With :

```
olApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
```

It returns this errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents and Settings\da7950\Mes documents\Dropbox\cheetahImporter\mapiImport.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(myMAPI.getContacts(*fields))
  File "D:\Documents and Settings\da7950\Mes documents\Dropbox\cheetahImporter\mapiImport.py", line 19, in getContacts
    for contact in filter(lambda x: x.Class == 40,self.mapiContacts) :
  File "D:\Documents and Settings\da7950\Mes documents\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x2\_Items.py", line 122, in __getitem__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(81, LCID, 1, 1, item)), "Item")
com_error: (-2147352567, "Une exception s'est produite.", (4096, u'Microsoft Office Outlook', u'Index de la matrice en dehors des limites.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

The message means "Matrix index out of bounds". The strangiest thing is that after I called EnsureDispatch, win32com.client.Dispatch doesn't works anymore. I have to uninstall pywin32 and reinstall it...

I'm running with Python2.7.3 64-bit with Outlook 2007 32-bit

Thanks

Comment: What's the pros and the cons of early binding (EnsureDispatch) and late binding (Disaptch) ? Is it ok if i keep my code like this (it will run on many platforms) ?

Comment: IMO `win32com.client.Dispatch` didn't work 'cause you had generated cache in `Temp\gen_py` folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. It's a bug win32com makepy...

The main problem is that Outlook is 1-based indexed for `olContactItem` (as opposed to 0-based index for python)

```
olApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")           
namespace = olApp.GetNamespace(u"MAPI")           
# olFolderContacts = 10 :           
mapiContacts = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(10).Items
for i in range(1,len(mapiContacts)+1) :
    contact = self.mapiContacts[i]
    ...
```

There is another problem with `contact.itemProperties`. All properties are case sensitive with `EnsureDispatch`, so :

```
contact.ItemProperties("FullName").Value
#       ^
```

works, but not :

```
contact.itemProperties("FullName").Value
#       ^
```

To get the names right, consult: [Microsoft Outlook ContactItem reference model on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem)